# Why is my animation render all white?

Tags: rendering, transparency, lighting

I'm working on a gold logo with a transparent background to throw on some videos. I'm in Cycles Render and it's taken me a long time just to get the glossy logo to look shiny. My render is all white or shows the world background, not sure why. Could you guys point me in the right direction? Any tips on how I can just have a gold logo without the clouds keeping the background transparent / what's wrong with my render settings? Many thanks in advance.

Here's what my render view looks like:
https://gyazo.com/ee8cb329c6b13f05b4dd7ed893333626

Here's a photo of my actual render:
https://gyazo.com/27ced9312ddb08897976049aea39ec74

Here's a link to my Blender file packed with textures if someone could please take a look:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gV01wETy5eX__zMRxH3eayb62O2P6I_2/view?usp=sharing

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but I did look at your file. With my limited knowledge (I'm a n00b myself), I will say that if you want to get rid of the clouds, you need to hide them so that they don't render. I tried it, and it seems to work (I did get a transparent background). Refer to this pic below:

[image]

Comment: In mine all those planes were for testing different things but I have them hidden in mine unless there is something that I'm missing

Comment: Hidden is one thing. Rendered is another. You need to hide from rendering. See the "camera" icon on the right of the eye for each mesh.

Comment: Ah thank you for that let me take a look appreciate it

Comment: Beautiful that looks like it took care of some of the issues I was having thank you